# Importing all modules in a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Here's my file hierarchy:

```
|--main.py
|--package/
   |--__init__.py
   |--a.py
   |--b.py
```

Now what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
# main.py
from package import *
print(package.a.MyClass)
print(package.b.my_function)
```

So basically I want it to automatically import everything that's inside the `package` package.
Is this possible?
I would rather not have to write the imports manually, as I want it to be "drag&drop your files here and you're done" kind of system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Python's [pkgutil.iter_modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules)

**Example:**

```
import pkgutil


for module_loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(["/path/to/module"]):
    ...
```

What you do with the iterated sub-modules is up to the user.

An alternative and commonly used approach is to use [pkg_resources](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) which you can also look into and I believe comes as part of [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

**Update:** The naive approach to this is to use `__import__` and `os.lsitdir()`:

```
import os

def load_modules(pkg):
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(pkg.__file__)):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            m = __import__("{}.{}".format(pkg.__name__, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
```

**NB:** This is not tested but should give you a *rough* idea.

Comment: How would I import them from here, if that's all I need to do? Use `__import__(name)` in the for loop?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Probably a little more work though :) There are many approaches to this.